# How to select the first radio button created using for loop element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a group of radio buttons, created dynamically using a for loop in jsp. I need that the first radio button be checked by default.
How can I do that via jquery?

```
<div id="groupATypeRadio">
   <%  for(SomeList list: someList .values())  {%>
   <span class="font-small pull-left marRight5"><%= list.label %></span>
   <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left"name="groupA" id="<%= list.id%>"  value="<%= list.getId()%>">
   <%} %>
</div>

<div id="groupBTypeRadio">
   <%  for(SomeList list: someList .values())  {%>
   <span class="font-small pull-left marRight5"><%= list.label %></span>
   <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left"name="groupB" id="<%= list.id%>"  value="<%= list.getId()%>">
   <%} %>
</div>

<div id="groupCTypeRadio">
   <%  for(SomeList list: someList .values())  {%>
   <span class="font-small pull-left marRight5"><%= list.label %></span>
   <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left"name="groupC" id="<%= list.id%>"  value="<%= list.getId()%>">
   <%} %>
</div>
```

I need to fetch the first radio button from each group and check it via jquery. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to your radio button container div `class="radio-groups"` and use the below to check every first radio button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".radio-groups").each(function() {
      $(this).find("input[type='radio']").first().prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

See a demo below

```js
$(".radio-groups").each(function() {
  $(this).find("input[type='radio']").first().prop('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="groupATypeRadio" class="radio-groups">

  <span class="font-small pull-left marRight5">1</span>
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupA" id="" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupA" id="" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupA" id="" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupA" id="" value="">

</div>

<div id="groupBTypeRadio" class="radio-groups">

  <span class="font-small pull-left marRight5">2</span>
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupB" id="" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupB" id="" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupB" id="" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupB" id="" value="">

</div>

<div id="groupCTypeRadio" class="radio-groups">

  <span class="font-small pull-left marRight5">3</span>
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupC" id="" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupC" id="" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="marRight5 pull-left" name="groupC" id="" value="">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using below:

To make it work for jquery version greater than or equal to 1.6

```
$("#groupATypeRadio input[type='radio']")[0].attr('checked', 'checked');
$("#groupBTypeRadio input[type='radio']")[0].attr('checked', 'checked');
$("#groupCTypeRadio input[type='radio']")[0].attr('checked', 'checked');
```

or

To make it work for older jquery version

```
$("#groupATypeRadio input[type='radio']")[0].prop('checked', true);
$("#groupBTypeRadio input[type='radio']")[0].prop('checked', true);
$("#groupCTypeRadio input[type='radio']")[0].prop('checked', true);
```